# Finding constants in a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, systems-of-equations, piecewise-continuity

The piecewise function is
$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
2,    & x \leq -1\\
ax+b, & -1 < x < 3\\
-2,   & x\geq 3
\end{cases}
$$

So I first find the limit of the first piece which is 
$$\lim_{x\to -1}f(x)=2 $$

Then I find the limit of the 2nd piece at -1 from the right
$$\lim_{x\to-1+}f(x)=-a+b $$

Then I repeat this for the 2nd and 3rd piece at 3
$$\lim_{x\to 3}f(x)=-2$$
$$\lim_{x\to 3-}f(x)=3a+b$$
Now I set the limits that approached the same number equal to each other
$$
\begin{split}
2  &= -a &+ b\\
-2 &= 3a &+b
\end{split}
$$
but this is where I get stuck because my prof. said to  added them normally but when I do this I get 
$$ 0=2a+2b$$

Comment: You have to solve the systems of equations. For example, you could add 3 times the first equation to the second equation to obtain the new equation $4b = 4 \implies b = 1$.

Comment: $b=-a=1${}{}{}{}{}

Comment: Context:  you should state that you want this piecewise function to be **continuous** if that is so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your last equation implies $a+b=0 \iff a = -b$ and the first one says $2 = b-a = b-(-b) = 2b \iff b = 1, a = -1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the linear system given by the two equations $2=-a+b$ and $-2=3a+b$. If you add the two equations and keep one of the two you obtain an equivalent system, hence you can solve $2=-a+b$ and $0=2a+2b$. But $0=2a+2b$ implies $b=-a$, hence substituting in the first equation we get $2=-a-a$, i.e. $2=-2a$m thus $a=-1$, It follows that $b=-a=-(-1)=1$.